# Information required on the Croatian Visa for Research Scholar/PhD

Tags: visas, study, croatia

I got into University of Zagreb, Croatia as Early Research Scholar/PhD in Cleopatra Project of EU.
I will be employed by the university and have received the hosting contract.

I need help in applying for the Visa for entry. As per my research, I have to apply for Visa C which is valid for 90 days and then apply for Temporary residence permit when I land. 
I check VFS global website,  I am confused as in which category of visa do I fit in ? Is it studies

My contract says my employer will provide me with the health insurance and stuff , do I need extract travel insurance when I travel in Croatia ?.

There are also dates like number of days in Croatia/expected date of departure for which I will be staying.
I am going to do PhD for next 3-4 years, what should I put into this section ?

I have tried calling/mailing the Embassy of Croatia in India, but either no one answers the phone or no response for email was received.

Please can anyone help me in this regard

Comment: Have you asked the university for advice? I’d expect them to be able to guide you and provide you with the relevant paperwork given that they’re employing you

Comment: I would think you should be applying for a D visa, not a C visa.  Regardless, this belongs on [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: @Traveller I have already received the hosting contract from the university. I also asked them for advice on the same but I was told to contact the embassy in India. It's just some of the information requirements that are confusing. Plus there is no clear cut documentation on the same anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I applied for a Visa D as a researcher to Austria. I too had the same questions, so I just walked into my visa appointment with those areas (ie. duration of stay and date of expected departure) blank and explained to the visa official that I was unsure of what to fill in given that I was staying for quite a long time.

In short, the officer told me to leave the "duration of stay" blank and to fill in the date of departure as the last day of my program. In my visa that is shown as "XX".

Regarding your insurance question, my institute provided an insurance document which the consulate accepted for my visa. So no need for extra insurance in my case and I suspect the same for your situation.

This is from my experience. I would recommend you go in with them blank and ask the official face to face.

Edit: Just realized you have to go through VFS, something I didn't have to do as I dealt with the consulate directly. Have you called VFS? They can usually clarify these questions over the phone.

Comment: @Ozzy...Thanks for the advice.I have called VFS multiple times but moment they hear the visa is for long duration they shut the conversation down saying VFS is only for short term duration. Anyways I have taken appointment of VFS and go on premise and check with them. The problem is they is no direct appointment related information available with Croatian Embassy in India. There are bunch on numbers and emails which are close to dead as no body responds on those numbers.

Comment: I found this contact info for you to contact the Ministry of Foreign Affairs directly:     "All questions regarding Croatia’s visa regime can be submitted at: vize@mvep.hr"

Comment: how did you take an appointment for your application at Croatian Embassy ?

Comment: Thnks will shoot out a mail immediately

Comment: I had an appointment with the Austrian consulate as they are the ones that handle visa applications for my place of residence.